# C++ error 4716 with float function

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am having a hard time with the return value with the float function. Everytime I try to put in a return value I keep getting the errors unknown value or you must put in a return value. I am very lost.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string studFirstName;
string studLastName;
float studExam1;
float studExam2;
float studExam3;
float studScore;
float studAvg;

void getStudName(string& studFirstName, string& studLastName);
void getStudExams(float& studExam1, float& studExam2, float& studExam3);
float calStudAvg(float studExam1, float studExam2, float studExam3);
void displayGrade(string studFirstName, string studLastName, float studavg);

int main ()
{
    cout << "Enter Student's First Name:";
    cin >> studFirstName;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter Student's Last Name:";
    cin >> studLastName;
    cout << endl;
}

void getStudExams(float& studExam1, float& studExam2, float& studExam3)
{    
    cout << "Enter score for Exam 1:";
    cin >> studExam1;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter score for Exam 2:";
    cin >> studExam2;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter score for Exam 3:";
    cin >> studExam3;
    cout << endl;
}

float calStudAvg(float studExam1, float studExam2, float studExam3)
{
    float studScore = (studExam1 + studExam2 + studExam3);
    float studAvg = (studScore/3);
    return; 
}

void displayGrade(string studFirstName, string studLastName, float studAvg)
{    
    cout << "Student's First Name:";
    getline (cin, studFirstName);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Student's Last Name:";
    getline (cin, studLastName);
    cout << endl;

    cout << left << "Student's Final Grade:"
    << right << studAvg << endl;

    if (studAvg >= 90)
        cout << "Grade = 'A'" << endl;
    else if (studAvg >= 80)
        cout << "Grade = 'B'" << endl;
    else if (studAvg >= 70)
        cout << "Grade = 'C'" << endl;
    else if (studAvg >= 60)
        cout << "Grade = 'D'" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Grade = 'F'" << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

if anyone has any ideas I really need the help! Thanks

Comment: return; ??? you either return studScore or studAvg.

Comment: I tried both and it gives me a fatal error.

Comment: You complained about compilation error. This solves the compilation error. You haven't showed how you are calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
float calStudAvg(float studExam1, float studExam2, float studExam3)

{
float studScore = (studExam1 + studExam2 + studExam3);

float studAvg = (studScore/3);

return; 
}
```

Simply putting return in your function block doesn't return anything. You have to explicitly specify what value you want that function to return. 
Like in your case it seems you want to do something like:-

```
return studAvg ;
```

Apart from that empty return signifies to compiler to return control to caller that means you can use empty return even in function whose return type is void.

Also, from mathematics side , make sure the scores , of which you are taking avg , are calculated out of same number. Otherwise you have to use weighted average.

Answer (score 0):

i dont't know actully what are you lokking the problem is where did u call these methods?, anyway  try this this will not shown any erros, and also your code system("pause")  It's slow. It's platform dependent. It's insecure. so please use anyothere methods

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string studFirstName;
string studLastName;
float studExam1;
float studExam2;
float studExam3;
float studScore;
float studAvg;

void getStudName(string& studFirstName, string& studLastName);
void getStudExams(float& studExam1, float& studExam2, float& studExam3);
float calStudAvg(float studExam1, float studExam2, float studExam3);
void displayGrade(string studFirstName, string studLastName, float studavg);

int main ()
{

cout << "Enter Student's First Name:";
cin >> studFirstName;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter Student's Last Name:";
cin >> studLastName;
cout << endl;
}

void getStudExams(float& studExam1, float& studExam2, float& studExam3)

{   

cout << "Enter score for Exam 1:";
cin >> studExam1;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter score for Exam 2:";
cin >> studExam2;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter score for Exam 3:";
cin >> studExam3;
cout << endl;
}

float calStudAvg(float studExam1, float studExam2, float studExam3)

{
float studScore = (studExam1 + studExam2 + studExam3);

float studAvg = (studScore/3);

return studAvg; 
}

void displayGrade(string studFirstName, string studLastName, float studAvg)

{   
cout << "Student's First Name:";
getline (cin, studFirstName);
cout << endl;

cout << "Student's Last Name:";
getline (cin, studLastName);
cout << endl;

cout << left << "Student's Final Grade:"
<< right << studAvg << endl;

if (studAvg >= 90)
    cout << "Grade = 'A'" << endl;
else if (studAvg >= 80)
    cout << "Grade = 'B'" << endl;
else if (studAvg >= 70)
    cout << "Grade = 'C'" << endl;
else if (studAvg >= 60)
    cout << "Grade = 'D'" << endl;
else
    cout << "Grade = 'F'" << endl;

}
```